# Influx database insert is to slow

Tags: go, influxdb

Using golang I want to insert some measurements in influxdb.

The code I'm using is:

```
type InfluxConnection struct {
    Url    string
    client influxdb2.Client
}

var influxToken = "<token>"
var org = "happypanda"
var bucket = "stocks"
var measurement = "stock_prices"

var clog = logger.Create()

func (ic *InfluxConnection) InitInfluxClient() {
    client := influxdb2.NewClientWithOptions(ic.Url, influxToken,
        influxdb2.DefaultOptions().
            SetApplicationName("pandalica").
            SetPrecision(time.Hour).
            SetHTTPRequestTimeout(360).
            SetBatchSize(5000).
            SetFlushInterval(5).
            SetMaxRetries(5).
            SetMaxRetryInterval(20000).
            SetExponentialBase(2).
            SetLogLevel(2).
            SetUseGZip(true))
    ic.client = client

}

func (ic *InfluxConnection) Insert(dt *data.ChartData) {

    timestamps := dt.Chart.Result[0].Timestamp
    closeArr := dt.Chart.Result[0].Indicators.Quote[0].Close
    highArr := dt.Chart.Result[0].Indicators.Quote[0].High
    lowArr := dt.Chart.Result[0].Indicators.Quote[0].Low
    openArr := dt.Chart.Result[0].Indicators.Quote[0].Open
    volumeArr := dt.Chart.Result[0].Indicators.Quote[0].Volume
    symbol := dt.Chart.Result[0].Meta.Symbol

    writeAPI := ic.client.WriteAPI(org, bucket)

    start := time.Now()
    points := []*write.Point{}
    for i := 0; i < len(timestamps); i++ {

        tags := map[string]string{
            "symbol": symbol,
        }
        fields := map[string]interface{}{
            "open":   openArr[i],
            "high":   highArr[i],
            "low":    lowArr[i],
            "close":  closeArr[i],
            "volume": volumeArr[i],
        }

        tt := timestamps[i]
        panda := write.NewPoint(measurement, tags, fields, time.Unix(tt, 0))

        points = append(points, panda)

    }
    clog.Printf("Compute data for %s took  : %s\n", symbol, time.Since(start))

    start = time.Now()

    for _, p := range points {
        writeAPI.WritePoint(p)
    }

    writeAPI.Flush()
    clog.Printf("Symbol %s had %d points. Write data took : %s\n", symbol, len(points), time.Since(start))
}

func (ic *InfluxConnection) Close() {
    ic.client.Close()
}
```

I'm measuring the time it takes to write the points and I receive some very high values:

```
INFO 2023/07/22 19:28:46.112083 influxDbHandler.go:103: Symbol AAPL had 10741 points. Write data took : 7m30.6125163s
INFO 2023/07/22 19:41:17.798841 influxDbHandler.go:103: Symbol AAPL had 10741 points. Write data took : 6m53.5446173s
```

Basically for 10k points I have 5+ minutes.

I even tried to play a little bit with influxdb config like query-concurrency but without success.

Additional I see in the console log.The number of this kind a logs are between 60-80 entries. I don't know if these are correlated.

```
2023/07/22 19:39:13 influxdb2client I! HTTP POST req to http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?bucket=stocks&org=happypanda&precision=s
```

How can I increase the insert performance?

**Later edit**

Based on erik258 comment, I've changed the flush interval.

- For flush interval equal with 2500 (2.5s) it took:

```
    INFO 2023/07/22 21:46:33.268855 influxDbHandler.go:103: Symbol AAPL had 10741 points. Write data took : 5m5.7841272s
```

- For flush interval equal with 1000 (1s) it took:

```
INFO 2023/07/22 21:56:48.233973 influxDbHandler.go:103: Symbol AAPL had 10741 points. Write data took : 5m4.1113099s
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling your program to identify the bottlenecks?

Comment: [default flush interval is `1_000`](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-go/blob/v2.12.3/api/write/options.go#L196). yours is 5.

Comment: @erik258 see my later edit. it didn't improve to much.

Comment: @M.Becerra not yet. I need first to learn how to use one ^^